# Force ProgressDialog to close upon destruction

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

**Environment:** I'm using wxPython Phoenix 3.0.3 and Python 2.7.10.

**Situation:** I have a simple ProgressDialog that works as intended, only it will not close automatically when finished. There is a close button in the dialog that is disabled until the progress is finished. At that time the dialog waits for the user to click the Close button.

**Problem:** I want to close it automatically (without waiting for user action).

**What I've Tried:** Calls to `Close()` and `Destroy()` don't work. I've used `Yield()` to ensure all events are handled and have tried sleeping for various periods of time to ensure all stacked up events are handled.

**Parameters:** I don't want to use threading, this problem is too simple to bother and I don't believe that is the issue (but if a simple solution is offered using threading, so be it).

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
# max progress for progress dialog
max_progress = len(unparsed_files)
progress_dlg = wx.ProgressDialog("Parsing", 'Processing...', max_progress, self, 
                                 style=wx.PD_ELAPSED_TIME)

# parse files
for i, uf in enumerate(unparsed_files):
    wx.Yield()
    progress_dlg.Update(i, 'Processing {}'.format(uf))
    self.parse(uf)

progress_dlg.Update(max_progress, 'Parsing completed')
progress_dlg.Destroy()
wx.Yield()
```

**Alternative Solution:** A modal dialog with no buttons that does not need any user action and can have a `wx.Gauge` that can be updated and then the dialog destroyed.

How can I close and destroy the ProgressDialog without waiting for the user to click the Close button (or use an alternate dialog without one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `wx.PD_AUTO_HIDE` flag to the style parameter.

From the [documentation](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/GenericProgressDialog.html#genericprogressdialog) of wxpython (*emphasis is mine*):

> Causes the progress dialog to disappear from screen as soon as the maximum value of the progress meter has been reached. **If this style is not present**, the dialog will become a modal dialog once the maximum value has been reached and **wait for the user to dismiss it**.